# Why the ui button is not working ? Clicking on it does nothing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a Main Menu empty GameObject under it as child a Canvas and under the Canvas as children the buttons. The first button is Start New Game.

The Main Menu button text is set to New Game.
A script name Main Menu is attached to the empty GameObject Main Menu.

[image: Main Menu]

When running the game and clicking on the button New Game it does nothing. And it's never getting to the method StartNewGame :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MainMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Canvas mainMenuCanvas;
    public PlayerController playerController;
    public CamMouseLook camMouseLook;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    public void StartNewGame()
    {
        mainMenuCanvas.enabled = false;
        playerController.enabled = true;
        camMouseLook.enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: do you see he interaction (color changes)?

Comment: Do you see the button press animation? The button should change colour to a grey tint and back when pressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the `EventSystem` object in your hierarchy, which is responsible for handling interactions with the UI. You can import it by right-clicking on the hierarchy and Add... > EventSystem.